# systemd user service not found after reboot

Tags: 18.04, systemd

I [set up syncthing as a systemd user service](https://docs.syncthing.net/users/autostart.html#using-systemd) on a 16.04 computer. Worked fine. Since I upgraded to 18.04 the service disappears upon reboot.

After rebooting, I see:

```
$ systemctl --user status syncthing.service 
Unit syncthing.service could not be found.
```

And `syncthing` is indeed not running.

Here is `~/.config/systemd/user/syncthing.service` (following the [example](https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/blob/master/etc/linux-systemd/user/syncthing.service), but note the binary is under my home dir):

```
[Unit]
Description=Syncthing - Open Source Continuous File Synchronization
Documentation=man:syncthing(1)

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/user/syncthing-prefix/syncthing -no-browser -no-restart -logflags=0
Restart=on-failure
SuccessExitStatus=3 4
RestartForceExitStatus=3 4

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I then run this:

```
$ systemctl --user enable syncthing.service
$ systemctl --user start syncthing.service
```

Following the setup instructions I used to install the user service originally.

After running the above two commands, I see:

```
$ systemctl --user status syncthing.service
● syncthing.service - Syncthing - Open Source Continuous File Synchronization
  Loaded: loaded (/home/user/.config/systemd/user/syncthing.service; enabled; 
  Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-11-06 15:28:16 PST; 4s ago
    Docs: man:syncthing(1)
Main PID: 4221 (syncthing)
  CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/syncthing.service
          └─4221 /home/user/syncthing-prefix/syncthing -no-b

Nov 06 15:28:18 kind syncthing[4221]: [XXXXX] INFO: Device XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXX
Nov 06 15:28:18 kind syncthing[4221]: [XXXXX] INFO: Device XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXX
Nov 06 15:28:18 kind syncthing[4221]: [XXXXX] INFO: Device XXXXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXX
Nov 06 15:28:18 kind syncthing[4221]: [XXXXX] INFO: GUI and API listening on 127
Nov 06 15:28:18 kind syncthing[4221]: [XXXXX] INFO: Access the GUI via the follo
Nov 06 15:28:18 kind syncthing[4221]: [XXXXX] INFO: Completed initial scan of se
Nov 06 15:28:18 kind syncthing[4221]: [XXXXX] INFO: Completed initial scan of se
Nov 06 15:28:18 kind syncthing[4221]: [XXXXX] INFO: Completed initial scan of se
Nov 06 15:28:19 kind syncthing[4221]: [XXXXX] INFO: Completed initial scan of se
Nov 06 15:28:20 kind syncthing[4221]: [XXXXX] INFO: Completed initial scan of se
```

as expected. And syncthing then works, as expected, until the next reboot.

Note that I have an encrypted home dir. This was the case when I was using 16.04, too.

Comment: Are you trying to start a service before logging in with the user? This should be enable using `sudo loginctl enable-linger USERNAME`

Comment: It could happen right when I log in or before. This set `Linger: yes` but didn't fix the reported issue on my machine.

Comment: Is your home folder encrypted? (ecryptfs?)

Comment: Yes, I have an encrypted home dir

Answer (score 1):

Credit to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417162/use-systemd-user-services-with-ecryptfs/545704#545704

---

It's a bug in the ecryptfs package configuration.
You can use a quick fix:
Open /etc/pam.d/common-session and switch the lines

```
session optional        pam_systemd.so
session optional        pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
```

to

```
session optional        pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
session optional        pam_systemd.so
```

so that pam_systemd.so is loaded after pam_ecryptfs.so

Answer (score 0):

You have the same problem than https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/417162/116970

I would suggest that you add a `After=` and a `Requires=` line on your `syncthing.service` in the `[Unit]` section so that syncthing is run after the home folder is mounted.

More spefically, you coud try:

```
[Unit]
Description=Syncthing - Open Source Continuous File Synchronization
Documentation=man:syncthing(1)
After=home-yourusername.mount
Requires=home-yourusername.mount

...
```

and replace *yourusername* with your user name

Comment: This didn't resolve the issue. I made this change, disabled the service, ran `systemctl --user daemon-reload`, enabled the service, and rebooted.